# How to search binaries in Simbad using spectral types

Tags: data-analysis

In the Simbad database there are many binary stars listed with the spectral classification of each component. For example, for $\alpha$ Centauri, [Simbad yields](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basic?Ident=alpha%20cent&submit=SIMBAD%20search) a spectral type of G2V+K1V.

My question is, what criterias do I have to input to search for all the binaries with a G and K component? And what If I want to search specifically for GV + KV binaries?

I don't know if this search can be done with the `sptypes` and `splum` search criteria.